# How to make a Shor's algorithm for an arbitrary number of qubits with Qiskit on a IBM machine?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, shors-algorithm

So suppose you want to do a Shor algorithm on an arbitrary number of qubits using an arbitrary $a$ (the base number in the periodic function $a^x \mod c$) and $c$ ( the factored number). Making the IQFT is easy for an arbitrary number of qubits because it has a clear pattern and it uses only Hadamard and controlled phase shifts gates. But what about the permutation gate that multiplies the function? I can make one for a 7 qubits Shor with 3 qubits $x$ and 4 qubits $f(x)$ using Toffolli gates but I don't know how I can code something that does it automatically for given $c$ and $a$. I also wonder how would you do it for a higher number of qubits. Any help, reading material or pointers on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0205095.pdf) can help you, that's what the implementation in Qiskit is based on.

Otherwise looking at the [implementation of Shor's algorithm in Qiskit itself](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/single_sample/shor/shor.html#Shor) might be insightful. The circuit for the algorithm is constructed in the method [`construct_circuit`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/single_sample/shor/shor.html#Shor.construct_circuit) and can be visualized with this snippet.

```
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import Shor
a, N = 2, 3
shor = Shor(N, a)
circuit = shor.construct_circuit()
print(circuit.draw())  # or circuit.draw(output='mpl') for a nicer looking diagram ;)
```

Warning: the circuit is huge and takes a long time to plot for large `N`!

Comment: Thanks very much! And yes, the circuits are indeed huge hahaha